# Job aborted due to stage failure: when converting a spark dataframe to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am running the below script in the Azure databricks notebook.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "false")
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{ServerName};databaseName={DBName};") \
.option("user", User) \
.option("password", Password) \
.option("query","SELECT col1,col2,col3......col30 from A except SELECT col1,col2,col3......col30 from B ") \
.load()
df=jdbcDF.toPandas()
```

I am trying to store the resultset in to a DF and converting in to a pandas DF to do some operations.

I am getting the below error when converting the DF in to pandas DF. i couldn't select any columns from the same DF even before converting it to Pandas DF.

NOTE: Query runs fine in the DB

Error:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1985.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1985.0 (TID 57569, 10.139.64.12, executor 15): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Aug' to data type int.

can someone help me with this error?

Thanks,
Prashanth

Comment: Are you sure that both tables, A and B, have the same schema?

Comment: @Gabip yes both the tables are in the same schema